# Is it possible to interact with an external program's command-line interface?

Tags: interoperability, external-calls

I am performing a calculation in *Mathematica* which relies on calls to an external program that acts as a black box for calculating a function $f$, and I would like to know if it is possible for Mathematica to interact with a command-line interface that asks for user input.

At the moment I am writing the arguments to my function $f$ in some external file `inputFile.txt`, and then running the external executable using one of the Run-related syntaxes:

```
inputstream=OpenRead["! ./external-program.x < inputFile.txt"]
ReadList[inputstream]
```

<sub>For the record, I'm running Mathematica 9 on Ubuntu 12.04.</sub>

While this is a perfectly OK way to do things, it does mean I need to write to a file, have `external-program` read it, and then delete the file. For a long calculation with many such calls, it is overhead that I'd like to avoid.

My external program does allow for command-line interaction, at least with a human user on a terminal, and this does not require piping in an already-written file. In practice, you run

```
./external-program.x
```

on a command line, and you are then required to input the multiple arguments and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after them.

**Is it possible to automate this sort of behaviour from within *Mathematica*?**

Comment: How is the file formatted? Have you tried piping that as a string instead using either `program <<< string` or `echo string | program`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anon pointed out, my problem was more of a poor knowledge of Unix rather than incomplete *Mathematica* chops, and a judicious use of pipes solves the issue.

Thus, instead of exporting a string to a file and using that as an input, as I had,

```
inputstring="sample input data";
Export["inputFile.txt",inputstring,"Text"]
inputstream=OpenRead["! ./external-program.x < inputFile.txt"]
ReadList[inputstream]
```

it is possible to pipe the string in directly on the command line using `|` and an `echo` command:

```
inputstring="sample input data";
inputstream=OpenRead["!echo \" "<>inputstring<>" \" | ./external-program.x < inputFile.txt"]
ReadList[inputstream]
```

Depending on the piping constructs on Windows, a similar approach may be possible.

I would still be stumped, however, with a more sophisticated application that requires actual interaction $-$ keyboard input that responds adaptively to the external program's output $-$, which is fortunately not my case. If someone does find a way and posts it here I will be happy to accept such an answer instead.