# Calling python code on an image directly (without writing to disk / stdin)

Tags: image, python

I have lots of image processing code written in python and would like to call it from within mathematica.

Is there a way to transmit the image data directly like with c++ and LibraryLink? I'd rather not pass the images via writing them to disk and having python reimport them and vice-versa, which would be a messy solution.

Comment: It would be messy, but it would still require the least work on your part.  Otherwise you would need to implement a complete link between Python and Mathematica.  *This is a huge project.* Expect it to take days-to-weeks of full time work to set up a working prototype even if you are well familiar with MathLink and numpy internals. It is, in theory, possible either using LibraryLink or MathLink, but in my opinion it is far better suited for MathLink. LibraryLink would force you to run the Python interpreter i the same process as the M kernel and would still require a lot of MathLink code.

Comment: The starting point would be exposing the MathLink API to Python. Some unsupported version of this, made for very old Python, used to ship in SystemFiles/Links/Python, but is no longer there in M10.

Comment: @Szabolcs ok, where did they move it?

Comment: I don't know.  It probably is removed.  If I remember right, it didn't even compile with current Python.  Using that would still have been (much) more work than writing the images to disk.

Comment: @Szabolcs what about using Python/C API calls

Comment: maybe `StartProcess` and pipe the data with `BinaryWrite`? simple example here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77063/2079