# Running a Fortran program and getting the results

Tags: external-calls, fortran

I'm trying to figure how to make Mathematica interact with a Fortran program that takes 2 parameters in a first input line, 3 parameters in a second input line and produces two lines as outputs. Below a simple example to illustrate my point:

```
program par  
  implicit none  
  integer            :: i,j  
  integer            :: k,l,m

  read (*,*) i, j  
  read (*,*) k, l, m  
  write (*,*) (i+j)*k, (i+j)-2*l  
  write (*,*) 2*l, 3*m, i-j 

end program par
```

When I run the code below in Mathematica, I get "EndOfFile" as a result.

```
pr = StartProcess["par"];
g[i_, j_, k_, l_, m_] := (Write[pr, ToString[i], ToString[j]]; 
Write[pr, ToString[k], ToString[l], ToString[m]]; Read[pr,Number];Read[pr, Number]);
g[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? What should Mathematica take as an input, and return exactly?

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77063/2079..  I suspect your `Write` may be running the numbers together with no spaces but cant test here..try adding `," ",` to the lists

Comment: In the Fortran code given above as an example, the "read" statements are the inputs (variables i and j in the first, and k, l and m in the second), and the "write" are the outputs.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
g[i_, j_, k_, l_, m_] := (
  WriteLine[pr, ToString[i] <> " " <> ToString[j]];
  WriteLine[pr, 
   ToString[k] <> " " <> ToString[l] <>
    " " <> ToString[m]];
  {Read[pr, Record], Read[pr, Record]})

pr = StartProcess["/home/louis/prgms/tmp/par"];
g[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // ColumnForm
```

`(*
  "           9          -5",
  "           8          15          -1"
 *)`

For numeric output, one could use this

```
g[i_, j_, k_, l_, m_] := (
  WriteLine[pr, ToString[i] <> " " <> ToString[j]];
  WriteLine[pr, 
   ToString[k] <> " " <> ToString[l] <>
    " " <> ToString[m]];
  {ToExpression /@ StringSplit[Read[pr, Record]],
   ToExpression /@ StringSplit[Read[pr, Record]]})

pr = StartProcess["/home/louis/prgms/tmp/par"];
output = g[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`(* {{9, -5}, {8, 15, -1}}  *)`

The above works for integer input to and output from the external program, which is okay for specified Fortran program.  If the external program, however, were reading and writing floating point numbers, scientific notation and/or text, we would want to do things a little differently.

Comment: Nicely done, thanks much! I would slightly modify the two Read statements of your proposed solution to get a numerical output: {Read[StringToStream[Read[pr, Record]], {Number, Number}], 
 Read[StringToStream[Read[pr, Record]], {Number, Number, Number}]}

Comment: `ReadList[pr,Number,2]` may do

Comment: This also works for numeric output:  `{Read[pr, {Number, Number}], Read[pr, {Number, Number, Number}]}`